# Newly installed laravel 5.2 wont read linked css

Tags: laravel

I have installed a Laravel 5.2 to run an existing project from my group mates but in my  laptop, the project will only read inline CSS, it cannot read Linked CSS, What seems to be the problem?

Comment: can u show us some snippet

Comment: Are the css files actually there? Sounds like you didn't generate them.

Comment: How are the css files linked? Where are they located in your project? Do you get any 404 errors in your developer tools?

Comment: its already there , it is an existing project , and also only in my unit where the css wont show

Comment: they are located in my project

Comment: i didnt ge any 404 errors sir

Comment: Please add your folder structure and code that generates the links to your question. We cannot help you without more information about your project.

Comment: So the CSS is there and you didn't get a 404 in your DevTools? Sorry, but that sounds like you're looking in the wrong places. Show us your chrome devtools where the CSS is loaded in the network tab

Comment: Did you run project via command `php artisan serve` or normal apache webserver ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use helper

```
url('path/to/css/file/in/public/folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put your assets in the public folder

Then you can use:

```
<link href="{{ url('path/file.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```